# is it possible to read video stream with opencv?

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, video-streaming

for [this](http://ayalon.castup.net/gmembed.asp?hn=castupay05&sn=1) stream:

is there a class that can capture the stream for manipulation?

all i found was tutorials about how to make client server, or read from computer connected cam.

Update:
it looks promising.
trying to open [this again](http://ayalon.castup.net/gmembed.asp?hn=castupay05&sn=1) failed , so i followed the asx which said:

```
<asx version="3.0">
    <!-- GMEmbed -->
    <title>CastUP: Ayalon</title>
    <entryref href="http://switch3.castup.net/cunet/gm.asp?format=wm&s=4A59334AD43141A7BFD73D7CE6B71560&ci=15369&ak=35143679&ClipMediaID=21329&authi=&autht=&dr=" />
</asx>
```

so tried [this](http://ayalon.castup.net/gmembed.asp?hn=castupay05&sn=1) which also didn't open(on cap.isOpen == false), too.

any suggestions?

the source:

```
Mat frame;
VideoCapture Ayalon("http://switch3.castup.net/cunet/gm.asp?format=wm&s=4A59334AD43141A7BFD73D7CE6B71560&ci=15369&ak=35143679&ClipMediaID=21329&authi=&autht=&dr=");
int delay = 1000/Ayalon.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);// (1 second / fps) = delay between frames
bool stop(false);               
if (!Ayalon.isOpened()) 
    return 1;                   
namedWindow("ayalon Stream");
while (!stop) {
    if (!Ayalon.read(frame))
        break;
    imshow("ayalon Stream",frame);
    if (waitKey(delay) >0 )
        stop = true;
}   
Ayalon.release();
waitKey(7000);
return 1;
```

Comment: see: https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~teammco/misc/udp_video/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and the nice feature is that the code is exactly the same as reading from a camera - see [Reading and Writing Images and Video](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html)

Comment: To be more specific, put your source IP address as the path parameter: `cap.open("http://ip:port/resource");`