# noise in webcam frames Python + Opencv

Tags: python, opencv, webcam, ip-camera, surveillance

I'm using Opencv 2.4.5 with python 2.7 to track people in video surveillance. At the beginning I used .avi and .mpeg videos to test my code, now I want to use a hcv-m100c camera. I am using a simple difference between frames (an initial frame compared with each frame) to identify the objects in movement, It works very well with the .avi and .mpeg videos I have, but when I use the camera the results are so bad because a lot of noise and stains appear in my video. I thought that the problem was my camera, but I made an .avi video with the same camera and I tested that video with my code and it works fine. 
Now, I'm using the cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG but the problem is still there.
So, I think I need to do a pre-processing when I use the camera

Comment: Is it because video codecs use filters to smooth out changes between frames and so that could be removing the noise?

Comment: I have tried that with the Gaussian Smoothing, same problem

Comment: Possibly you could [stream](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Streaming%20media%20with%20ffserver) the [video camera](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20capture%20a%20webcam%20input) with something like ffmpeg which can transcode as well and then use OpenCV to read the [network stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513304/is-it-possible-to-read-video-stream-with-opencv)

Comment: It might be easier to use [VLC](http://geraldnaveen.blogspot.com.au/2009/04/streaming-webcam-using-vlc.html) to stream instead.

Comment: I am using this function to capture the video from the camera, `cap  = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` so, How to use the VLC stream in this case? thank you in advance

Comment: I think if you follow that VLC link above, change the cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) to cap = cv2.VideoCapture("VLC_IP"), maybe cap = cv2.VideoCapture("127.0.0.1").

Comment: I forgot to post my solution, I made a local streamming with VLC creating an RTSP with this code `vlc "http://192.168.180.60:82/videostream.cgi?user=admin&pwd=" --sout "#transcode{vcodec=mp2v,vb=800,scale=1,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:duplicate{dst=rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/output.mpeg},dst=display}" --sout-keep` , so, I got this link rtsp://:8554/output.mpeg and now I can use it in OpenCV as follows:
`cap=cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://:8554/output.mpeg")` .. Thank you @dilbert

Comment: Has it helped with the noise problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness:

Solution concept:

Possibly you could [stream](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Streaming%20media%20with%20ffserver%20stream) the [video camera](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20capture%20a%20webcam%20input) with something like ffmpeg which can transcode as well and then use OpenCV to read the network stream. It might be easier to use [VLC](http://geraldnaveen.blogspot.com.au/2009/04/streaming-webcam-using-vlc.html) to stream instead.

Solution detail:

VLC Stream code (Shell):

```
vlc "http://192.168.180.60:82/videostream.cgi?user=admin&pwd=" --sout "#transcode{vcodec=mp2v,vb=800,scale=1,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=??44100}:duplicate{dst=rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/output.mpeg},dst=display}" --sout-keep
```

OpenCV Code (Python):

```
cap=cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://:8554/output.mpeg")
```